# Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame on subdomains

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have 2 vhosts setup with different subdomains; `x.domain.com` and `y.domain.com`. I'm rendering iframes from `x` in `y`. So issues rendering and displaying the iframe but getting cannot access the iframe contents. I have no headers set at the moment and tried to solve it with `csp` but couldn't get around the error.

x.domain.com/frame.html:

```
<html>
  <body>
  </body>

  <script>
    function myFunc() {
      console.log('called');
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

y.domain.com:

```
let iframe = (iframe_element.contentWindow || iframe_element.contentDocument);
if (iframe.document) iframe = iframe.document;
iframe.myFunc();
```

`postMessage` is not option as I can't modify iframe contents.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy

Comment: The idea of the strictened COEP (dropped `document.domain`) is to provide "inter-human contact" between the domains, that is you can either control the other domain, or you contact the owner and ask for support for your domain. Otherwise you simply can't access cross-domain embedded content in a browser.